# Why does a pendulum in the magnetic field experience a damping force from eddy currents?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

Why does a pendulum swinging in the magnetic field experience a damping force from eddy currents? In other words why does the pendulum come to rest sooner in the magnetic field?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does a pendulum swinging in the magnetic field experience a damping force from eddy currents?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/783104/why-does-a-pendulum-swinging-in-the-magnetic-field-experience-a-damping-force-fr)

Comment: Alex, welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. I’m voting to close this question because it is almost an exact duplicate of the question you asked yesterday that was closed as Homework-like. If you want you can try to improve that question and request it be reopened, but be sure to look at this [meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a moving metal object swinging through a magnetic field gets currents induced in it as it moves. those eddy currents produce their own magnetic field which is in opposition to the external magnetic field. the force developed by the two magnetic fields acts in a direction opposite the motion of the pendulum, fighting its movement.